# AngularFire2 getting UID and using in any page

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In Ionic(AngularFire2) application, for every page i need to get Firebase User UID, to get related data from Firebase database. For example, on Firebase there is a node('/users') and its key is FireBase Auth User UID.

```
  {
  "users" : {
    "LYW6i8sTbWauCvkXULIbszIWOdm1" : {
      "cellPhone" : "123321",
      "name" : "Name1",
      "userType" : "0"
    },
    "i4KSAzO2UhakowLKOZCa0ZeohRH3" : {
      "cellPhone" : "43343",
      "name" : "Name2",
      "userType" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using observables to get the UID, for every page again and again. I think there will be lots of subscriber and everytime ionic application makes request to Firebase Auth Server to get user UID ?

For example.

```
export class AccountProfilePage {

      user = {} as User
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    private afDb:AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth:AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  updateProfile(){
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(authState=>{
        this.afDb.object('users/'+authState.uid).update({
          cellPhone:this.user.cellPhone
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Is it the correct way ?

Comment: You should create a service and store your uid in the service, the service created once while you inject it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service which is included in the `Providers` section of your `app.module.ts`. This way the service keeps its state across the whole app.

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`auth.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private uid: string;

  setUid(uid: string): void {
    this.uid = uid;
  }

  getUid(): string {
    return this.uid;
  }
}
```

When the user logs into the application do `setUid(usersUid)` then on any page you can include the `auth.service` in the constructor and do a `getUid` and it will get the UID out of the service.

```
export class AccountProfilePage {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    someMethod() {
      this.authService.getUid(); // Returns UID
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder, in the setUID method, i am using an subscription method() to get authState, right ? Its behaviour is  same as stream, as far as i know ? Can we think, there will be always opened stream, which looks for user authstate ?

Comment: And one more question, i am injecting AngularFireAuth service in any page. Doesn't it have its own state  and keeps its state across the whole app ?

Comment: The state keeps across the whole app providing you're injecting the AngularFireAuth into a root module?

Comment: Yes i am injecting AngulureFireAuth into the root module.

Comment: In that case yes, it's the same state across our whole app.